# SQLAlchemy Relationships - Beginners traps

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i started learning python3 with SQLAlchemy. No i created a quick example Database with a User Table and an Group Table.

```
CREATE TABLE `USER` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_groups_idx` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_groups` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `GROUPS` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `GROUPS` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `GroupName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Quick and dirty, just for learning it. Every User is in a group (not multiple) and every Group can relate to many user.
So it is an Many-to-one relationship if i am not wrong.

To build my Relationship bidirectional (with the example from SqlAlchemy) i have to back_populate both classes in my mapping. But when i start my test, i get the following message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Groups.users - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specifya 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

My code is just on script for testing. Maybe someone with more experience could point me to my problem:

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import PrimaryKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKeyConstraint

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'USER'

    ID = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('NAME',String)
    username = Column('USERNAME', String)

    group_id = Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('group_id'))
    group = relationship("Groups", back_populates="users")


class Groups(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'GROUPS'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    groupName = Column('GroupName', String)
    users = relationship("User", back_populates="group")

engine = create_engine('mysql://test:test@localhost/TEST')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

for instance in session.query(User).order_by(User.ID):
    print(instance.ID, instance.username, instance.group_id)

session.close();
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with foreign key declaration for group_id and it can be done like below to resolve error - sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError

```
 group_id = Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('GROUPS.id'))
```

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks, of course i need the Table and PK from my target object.